# Sticky Footer Bootstrap 4 Not At Bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with a web app front end with Bootstrap 4 and am trying to make a footer that is stickied to the bottom of the viewport whether the content forces it to the bottom or not.  It also seems like this question has been asked multiple times before, but none of the solutions seem to solve my issue.  In other words, I am trying to create a footer that starts on the bottom of the page if the content doesn't fill the page; however, I don't want a fixed footer that covers up content when the page is scrollable.

Here's the HTML I have so far:

```
        <footer class="container-fluid text-center py-5 mt-auto footer" id="footer">
            <div class="row mx-auto footer-row">
                <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">
                    <i class="fas fa-dna footer-dna fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md">
                    <h5>Features</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                        <li><a href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Random feature</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team feature</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another one</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Last time</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md">
                    <h5>Resources</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                        <li><a href="/newsletter">Sign Up For Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Resource name</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another resource</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Final resource</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md">
                    <h5>About</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </footer>
```

As it stands now, the footer is below the final content on the page and not necessarily at the bottom depending on the amount of content.  Here's a codepen with the HTML and CSS: https://codepen.io/franchise/pen/LYpjxYM.  What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
  background-color: #951010;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Replace the footer class with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've tried this before, but while that achieves the goal of the footer being stickied to the bottom of the page, it covers any content that goes past the footer's original location.

Comment: Normally. The behavior should be the footer moves down as the content on that page grows. So I think there is no need to make it static. If you want to make it static explicitly then use calc(100vh-header+footer) on the body.